# literalinclude : how to include only a variable using pyobject?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using Sphinx to document parts of my Python code.

I would like to include only a variable from my class in my documentation.

For example, I tried this but without success :

```
.. literalinclude:: MyClass.py
    :pyobject: MyClass.aVariable
    :language: python
```

I see only one solution but if my code change in the next release the line numbers of the variable could change :

```
.. literalinclude:: MyClass.py
    :language: python
    :lines: 2-3
```

Is there another solution to filter only this variable ?

Comment: Does it work if you include a method instead of a variable?

Comment: @mzjn Yes, I tried :pyobject: MyClass.__init__ and it works.

Comment: It's the same for me. It might be a bug; I'm not sure. The documentation does not mention variables; it says "you can select a class, function or method to include using the pyobject option" (http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/code.html?highlight=literalinclude#directive-literalinclude).

Answer (score 2):

As workaround, I use the start-after and end-before options but I have to add two comments in my code before and after the variables.

For example :

The class :

```
class MyClass():
    # Start variables
    aVariable = {"a":123 , "b":456}
    # End variables 
        def __init__(self):
            pass
```

The RST file :

```
.. literalinclude:: MyClass.py
    :start-after: # Start variables 
    :end-before: # End variables 
    :language: python
```

It's not perfect, but it works.